# get data and count from table with join from two different tables

Tags: mysql, join

I have three tables `activity_log`, `user`, `staff`. I have to select data from `activity_log` to identify which user has done which activity.

This is structure of `activity_log` table

```
CREATE TABLE `activity_log` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `os` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `api` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**Dumping data for table `activity_log`**

```
INSERT INTO `activity_log` (`id`, `user_id`, `os`, `api`) VALUES
  (1, 1, 'web', 'user/login'),
  (2, 2, 'web', 'user/report'),
  (3, 1, 'android', 'user/login'),
  (4, 2, 'ios', 'user/data'),
  (5, 3, 'android', 'user/category'),
  (6, 3, 'web', 'user/result'),
  (7, 3, 'ios', 'user/send_sms');
```

This is structure of `user` table

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**Dumping data for table `user`**

```
INSERT INTO `user` (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`) VALUES
  (1, 'Yogesh', 'Kale'),
  (2, 'Sunit', 'Desai'),
  (3, 'Paresh', 'Godambe');
```

This is my `staff` table

```
CREATE TABLE `staff` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**Dumping data for table `staff`**

```
INSERT INTO `staff` (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`) VALUES
  (1, 'abcd', 'asas'),
  (2, 'ajay', 'shinde'),
  (3, 'kapil', 'parab');
```

But I have  to join `activity` log on one condition. That condition is based on `os` column in `activity_log` table. That condition is if `os` column contain value as `web` then I have to join `user_id` of `activity_log` with `id` column of `staff` table and if `os` column contain value as `ios` or `android` then I have to join user_id of activity_log with id column of user table. 
I need two different queries one for getting data with columns `id` and `api` from `activity_log`, `first_name`, `last_name` from either `staff` or `user` and another for getting total `count` for same above condition. I have given my table schema for reference.

I have tried following query for getting data

```
SELECT
    al.id as id,
    CONCAT(u.first_name, ' ', u.last_name) as user_name,
    al.api
FROM
    activity_log al
JOIN
    user u
ON
    u.id = al.user_id
WHERE
    al.os IN('android','os')
UNION ALL
SELECT
    al.id as id,
    CONCAT(st.first_name, ' ', st.last_name) as user_name,
    al.api
FROM
    activity_log al
JOIN
    staff st
ON
    st.id = al.user_id
WHERE
    al.os = 'web'
```

This above query returns me right data. But I dont know how to get count with above condition. Thats where I stuck in this. If possible please give me alternate queries for getting data and count.

Please help me in this. I spent whole day to figure out this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `UNION ALL` to get the required data.

Query 1:

```
select al.id, al.api,s.first_name, s.last_name from activity_log al inner join staff s on al.user_id=s.id where al.os='web' 
UNION ALL 
select al.id, al.api,u.first_name, u.last_name from activity_log al inner join user u on al.user_id=u.id where al.os!='web'
```

Query 2:

```
select 
    (select count(*) from activity_log al, staff s where al.user_id=s.id and al.os='web') as webcount, 
    (select count(*) from activity_log al, user u where al.user_id=u.id and al.os!='web') as othercount
```

I hope this gives you a direction for your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
SELECT ...,count(*) FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON ... WHERE ...
```